# WordPress query posts on scroll laggy/skips

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, performance

I have a website that on the homepage contains images/sliders standard page content etc. Once the page loads, it scrolls nice and smoothly. But I have a section about half way down that queries and displays WordPress Posts (see code below). When I view it in Google Chrome, while scrolling in that section, the website becomes laggy/skips and doesn't smoothy scroll like the rest of the home page.

Is there a way or something to include that will have WordPress query the posts faster or better or is there another reason as to why scrolling in that section becomes laggy?

```
<?php
    $temp = $wp_query; 
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
    $wp_query->query('no_found_rows=true&showposts=6&post_status=publish' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="newspagearticle full">
            <div class="newsthumb">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="homenewsheader">
                <div class="newsdate">
                    <div><?php the_time('M') ?></div>
                    <?php the_time('d'); ?>
                </div>
                <h2>
                    <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <?php
                            $thetitle = $post->post_title; /* or you can use get_the_title() */
                            $getlength = strlen($thetitle);
                            $thelength = 200;
                            echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
                            if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "...";
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- /newspagearticle -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: How many posts are you loading?

Comment: I'm only loading 6 on the page but have lots in the backend ~200

Comment: Have you tried using the profiling tools built into chrome?